# Displaying a Screensaver with an Away Message

Tags: windows, screensaver

I'm looking for an application that would lock my computer and display a screensaver with an away message that I set when I lock it. The idea is that when I go off somewhere during work, my co-workers would know where I'm off to instead of puzzling over my empty desk.

Does such an application exist?

If not, how would I go about making something like this?

I have developing experience but have never dealed with screensavers or locking windows before.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set a password to your account.
Press Windows+L which will lock your screen and will require your password to get back in.
As for leaving a message you can use marquee or 3d text screen savers to leave a message

Answer (score 2):

I know it's not really the answer you're after, but have you considered just using Post-It™ Notes?

Answer (score 0):

Most version of Windows have either the Marquee or 3D Text screensaver and give you the option of "On resume, display logon screen."  You could just set the text of the screensaver to indicate where you are and why you are not at your desk, and when you return you have to put your password in to resume work.  Is that not sufficient?

Answer (score 0):

Consider just using a screensaver with a passworded account.  Have the screen saver timeout be very short...a minute or so.